# CSS3: resize property to an image

Tags: css, image-resizing

if it possible to resize an image,  using the [CSS3 resize property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp)? I noticed it is for block elements, but is there any workaround or possible solution?
I know I might use the [jQuery UI resizable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) but I would like to apply this CSS3 technique.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can use CSS3 resize on images. The documentation states:

> Note: The resize property applies to elements whose computed overflow
>   value is something other than "visible".

You can however, place an image inside of a div that is made the same size as your image and apply the CSS3 resize to that.

```
<div style="height: 41px; width:114px; resize:both; overflow:hidden;">
     <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/curie11-sr.png">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I knew that method, but was waiting for some "magic" solution for images...

Comment: also, did you notice that this doesn't allow to reduce the size in Chrome?

Comment: You can put image in div, but you can not scale it smaller then natural image size.

Comment: @maza23 You can, now, in Chrome 120. Seems that was fixed.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, though, this seems to defeat `<img srcset ...>` scaling. Unlike resizing the entire content area, whatever size image is used on initial load is the one that's scaled inside the `<div>`, even when the it grows large enough for the next-higher size bucket. (Not to mention, it could really use some of JQuery's JavaScript to lock the aspect ratio of the `<div>`.)